# How to display custom message when record is not work using SQL STORED PROCEDURE in SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having difficulty to get a clue how to display custom message when parameter value does not match with existing record.  Can anyone help me please?
I am using **SQL MANAGEMENT STUDIO**

Thanks

```
CREATE PROCEDURE EmployeeDetail @Emp_num int AS
BEGIN TRY 
    SELECT EMP_CODE,EMP_TITLE,EMP_LNAME,EMP_FNAME,EMP_INITIAL,EMP_CODE,STORE_CODE
    FROM Employee
    WHERE Emp_code = @Emp_num;
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        --Comment/Uncomment the appropriate line.
        PRINT N'No Employees were found.';
        --THROW 56789, N'No Employees were found.', 10; --Use an Error code appropriate for your environment
    
END
```

I have tried sql exeptional handling but its not working. I am expecting For example, if  Employee number is not exists in employee table then display the ID not found message rather than a blank result.

Comment: There is no error to throw, maybe you want to throw an error if no row found, but I would not throw any error in SQL I would do this in the calling code

Comment: @Andrew Can you please help me or give me an example.Thanks

Comment: What's calling this store procedure? C#, Python, php...etc. The calling code should get the results, check if there is are 0 items and then throw an error from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to check the value of `@@ROWCOUNT` and then `PRINT`/`THROW` your error:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE EmployeeDetail @Emp_num int AS
BEGIN
    SELECT {Your List Of Columns} --Don't use *
    FROM dbo.Employee
    WHERE Emp_code = @Emp_num;

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        --Comment/Uncomment the appropriate line.
        PRINT N'No Employees were found.'
        --THROW 56789, N'No Employees were found.', 10; --Use an Error code appropriate for your environment
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have implemented you solution but its still showing blank result instead of message.

Comment: Then you aren't consuming the `PRINT`/`THROW` in the application layer; that is a *different* question.

Comment: Basically I want to display matching employee record if does not match then show message.

Comment: Which is an application layer problem, @Yasir . It has *nothing* to do with the SQL player.

Comment: I am using local SQL server. So its mean there is problem in my server.

Comment: I don't follow what that comment has to do with the question here, @Yasir .

Comment: So, if I adding THROW 56789 then intellsense giving an error on next END like Syntax error expecting ','

Comment: @Yasir it's not just `THROW 56789`...

Comment: I am going to edit the question. I am using SQL Managament Studio for this purpose